# unable to output birthday after adding timestampdiff to query to get the age in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

good day,

i am fairly new to php and i have been googling all day to get the output i wanted but i was not able to find one.

php

```
 $query="SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDATE, CURDATE())
 AS BDATE FROM perinfo";
 $showquery=mysql_query($query,$con);
```

this php code will display all the employees FNAME,LNAME and AGE; i want to have another column added for BIRTHDATE but due to the timestampdiff added to BDATE; i was not able to display the employees birthday.

i tried changing the alias (not sure if this is the right way to call it) BDATE to AGE and added an echo for it but that did not work; my question is how will i be able to add the bdate on my query to get the display i wanted

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean something like `... BDATE, CURDATE())
 AS BDATE, BIRTHDATE FROM ...`

Comment: @RubahMalam thanks for taking time to reply to my question; i was able to figure out the answer while waiting for reply :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

never mind guys i was able to find the answer i was looking for; kindly ignore the question.

for other people who might be having the same issue you can use the link as a reference.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

i missed two things on my code

1. i named the alias the same as my column name.
2. forgot to echo out the alias.

   $query = "SELECT FNAME, LNAME,BDATE, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDATE, 
    CURDATE()) AS AGE FROM perinfo";
    $showquery=mysql_query($query,$con);

   echo $row ['AGE'];

Comment: You need to post the useful code from the link - otherwise this post will get auto-flagged as being a link-only answer!